# "Your filters contain a field 'status' that doesn't appear on your model definition nor it's relations" (Strapi)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, controller, strapi

https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/guides/draft.html#apply-our-changes

I am customizing my own API, which of course I would like to filter only posts with status published, so I followed the documentation above to see how it works.

I actually use the exact code except for my own model so my code is below

```
'use strict';
const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');

/**
 * Read the documentation (https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/controllers.html#core-controllers)
 * to customize this controller
 */

module.exports = {
  async find(ctx) {
    let entities;

    console.log(ctx.query, 'before');
    ctx.query = {
      ...ctx.query,
      status: 'published',
    };

    console.log(ctx.query, 'after');
    if (ctx.query._q) {
      entities = await strapi.services.post.search(ctx.query);
    } else {
      entities = await strapi.services.post.find(ctx.query);
    }

    return entities.map(entity => sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.post }));
  }
};
```

then I do a normal get API call `localhost:1337/posts`

but I get this error though

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Your filters contain a field 'status' that doesn't appear on your model definition nor it's relations"
}
```

I will be adding things on later for the query as needed but even following the documentation, this error occurs, if I am not overriding the default controller, the API works fine.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions and advice.

EDIT:

`models/post.settings.json`

```
{
   "kind":"collectionType",
   "collectionName":"posts",
   "info":{
      "name":"Post",
      "description":""
   },
   "options":{
      "increments":true,
      "timestamps":true,
      "draftAndPublish":true
   },
   "attributes":{
      "title":{
         "type":"string",
         "required":true
      },
      "images":{
         "collection":"file",
         "via":"related",
         "allowedTypes":[
            "images"
         ],
         "plugin":"upload",
         "required":false
      },
      "publishedAt":{
         "type":"datetime"
      },
      "expiresAt":{
         "type":"datetime"
      },
      "content":{
         "type":"richtext"
      },
      "link":{
         "type":"string"
      },
      "categories":{
         "collection":"category",
         "via":"posts"
      },
      "slug":{
         "type":"uid",
         "targetField":"title"
      },
      "originalPrice":{
         "type":"decimal"
      },
      "salePrice":{
         "type":"decimal"
      },
      "thumb":{
         "model":"file",
         "via":"related",
         "allowedTypes":[
            "images"
         ],
         "plugin":"upload",
         "required":false
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your model code?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan added

Comment: The native Draft & Publish feature has been released in version 3.2. We suggest you to use the native feature instead of this guide.

This guide is still useful if you want to see the concept of "force filtering" in action.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you don't have a `status` field in your model. Add an `enumeration` field `status` with the values `draft`, `published`, and `archived` to your model as mentioned [here](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/guides/draft.html#example).

Comment: ok but by doing so, that means we cannot use the default `status` by strapi, which means the publish / unpublish button  from admin dashboard would be useless.  Instead we will use the `enumeration` field created  instead?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The order of the routes matters!!!

Comment: Could you find a way to augment your answering picture of free-hand adorned text with a text-only version? That would make your answer helpful for more people.

Answer (score 0):

As @Renderlife has mentioned, order of routes matters. For example

Below code will not work, it will throw error, if we try to access `http://localhost:1337/bookings/feedback?` , however if we change order of json object then it will work as expected.

```json
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/bookings",
      "handler": "booking.find",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/bookings/count",
      "handler": "booking.count",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/bookings/:id",
      "handler": "booking.findOne",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/bookings/feedback",
      "handler": "booking.feedback",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/bookings",
      "handler": "booking.create",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "PUT",
      "path": "/bookings/:id",
      "handler": "booking.update",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "DELETE",
      "path": "/bookings/:id",
      "handler": "booking.delete",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Working example: look at the order of `/bookings/feedback`

```json
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/bookings",
      "handler": "booking.find",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/bookings/count",
      "handler": "booking.count",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/bookings/feedback",
      "handler": "booking.feedback",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/bookings/:id",
      "handler": "booking.findOne",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },

    {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/bookings",
      "handler": "booking.create",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "PUT",
      "path": "/bookings/:id",
      "handler": "booking.update",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "DELETE",
      "path": "/bookings/:id",
      "handler": "booking.delete",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```